# How to change label into data from SQL Server database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2017

I want the label to display the FirstName from the database but it doesn't show the data that was stored, I tried using this

```
Loginusername.Text = "Select FirstName from Users where Username='" & My.Forms.Login.loginuser & "'"`
```

`Loginusername` is the name of the label while `loginuser` is the username typed in by the user in the log in form

Comment: You have to load the data from the database to a table first.

Comment: can you give me an example on how to do it?? kinda new to vb

Comment: Have ypu created the table already?  What's its name?

Comment: yes, the table's name is Users

Comment: It's not for us to provide examples that you can easily find for yourself with a web search. SO is a place to get help with the stuff that you can't do for yourself, not the stuff that you can't be bothered to do for yourself.  Look first and then make an effort.  If what you do doesn't work, then ask.

Comment: I put "how to retrieve data from database in vb.net" in google and got 1,630,000 results. Surely there is something to help you there.

Comment: Did you really think that the code could figure out where your server is, what the database name is and if you are allowed to connect all from your Select command?

Comment: Also, NEVER concatenate strings to build command text. Always use parameters. You are risking Sql injection which can destroy your database.

Comment: You can try using `ADO.NET` to achieve it. Please refer to the document [SqlConnection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.8)